# How do I increase protobuf serialization size when reading data in Spark to avoid InvalidProtocolBufferException.sizeLimitExceeded exception?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, protocol-buffers

I am reading a stream of protobuf data from HDFS using Spark 1.3. However, some of the protobufs are too large and I get this exception:

> com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message was too large.  May be malicious.  Use CodedInputStream.setSizeLimit() to increase the size limit.at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.sizeLimitExceeded(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:110)"

Here is how I am reading the data:

> sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("protobuf.serialization.max.size", "268435456") //increasing this size doesn't help
>
> val data = sc.newAPIHadoopFileLongWritable, SomeProtobufClass,
>         SequenceFileInputFormat[LongWritable, SomeProtobufClass]